# When using the Graph API to access a folder on a SharePoint site, we get the following “itemNotFound” error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, spfx

Problem:

Only one of our three Office 365 tenant, a Graph call fails with an itemNotFound error. The other two tenants works as expected.

Case:

When using the Graph API to access a folder on a SharePoint site, we get the following "itemNotFound" error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "4ea1730c-1b1d-4993-8335-4e10cc3b47c1",
            "date": "2020-04-27T09:15:37"
        }
    }
}

Query Information:

This is the final query that fails: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/54929188-6c44-4555-a85b-27a698b9b572/drive/root:/InvestmentTemplate

To find information to "build" the query, that fails, we are using this query to find the site id:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/testnrep.sharepoint.com:/sites/DocumentTemplates

To recreate test data:

1. Create a site with the url "/sites/DocumentTemplates"
2. Add a folder name "InvestmentTemplate" to the Shared Document library

The full folder url: https://ZXY.sharepoint.com/sites/DocumentTemplates/Shared%20Documents/InvestmentTemplate

Comment: Before you test the graph API in your code, go to the graph Api in microsoft site and test once you API , is retrurning any data or same issue you are found ..

Comment: @RajkiranSwain, Thank you. God point. The test output in my question is actually from the Graph Explorer

Comment: I reproduced a similar scenario in my lab environment.  The query succeeds when running as a tenant administrator.  Query fails as a normal user.  I removed all permissions granted to Graph Explorer and added them back one by one.  Once I granted Files.Read.All (not just Files.Read) for the non-admin user I was then able to successfully query a similar endpoint. Does any of this apply to your scenario?

Comment: @BrianT.JackettMSFT, Thank you for your comment. Yes it was also a permission issue. So the problem was a mix of my account permission when testing in the Graph Explore and the permission for the Azure AD App permission. The permission need in my case (for both my account the the Azure AD App) is Microsoft Graph > Sites.FullControl.All. But the Microsoft Graph was also a bit off. The other thing that was wrong is. When query for a folder in a document library. The url have a :/ between root and directory name e.g. {driveid}/Root:/folder name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-stating comment above as answer as this appears to address your scenario.

I reproduced a similar scenario in my lab environment.  The query succeeds when running as a tenant administrator.  Query fails as a normal user.  I removed all permissions granted to Graph Explorer and added them back one by one.  Once I granted Files.Read.All (not just Files.Read) for the non-admin user I was then able to successfully query a similar endpoint.

As for the ":/" syntax, yes that is common to use a ":" when specifying a relative location within the siteUrl or path in a document library.  See examples for [site-id using relative URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#access-a-site-by-server-relative-url) or [relative path within document library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#list-children-of-a-driveitem-with-a-known-path).